# Swap span content if URL contains

Tags: javascript, html

I have a need to swap a URL (a YouTube playlist) within an iFrame using one page with unique URLs.

I have some videos of doctors that I've setup as a playlist.  We want to run Adword campaigns with unique URL's to a single page and the URL within the embedded IFrame (a YouTube playlist) would get swapped.  I've figured out how to target a unique video within a playlist, but I need a to swap the embedded URL so the correct video plays to support the ad.  So...

Adword campaign target healthcare subject 1 = ourwebsite.org/ourpage.aspx

Adword campaign target healthcare subject 3 = ourwebsite.org/ourpage.aspx#video3

My original HTML is this.

```
<div class="videoframe"> <span id="video"><iframe width="320" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P2LBebH1IBU?list=PLnVpR1DYS2MHt8Ormx_CETTIy3cfjtMEU" frameborder="0"></iframe> </span></div>
```

I added the script hoping it would swap the contents of the span id="video".

```
<script> 
if (window.location.href.indexOf("video3") != -1) {

document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<iframe width="320" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q8msNGWLdwI?list=PLnVpR1DYS2MHt8Ormx_CETTIy3cfjtMEU" frameborder="0"></iframe>";

}
</script>
```

The URL I'm using has an anchor in it, like this.

```
ourwebsite.org/ourpage.aspx#video3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler method of achieving the effect that I believe you are going for.

Define an object which holds all the video locations associated with their respective hash targets.

If there is a hash target and the hash target matches one in the object, then we change the source of the `iframe`.

You don't actually have to change the `iframe`'s html.

```
var videos = {
    '#video1': '//youtube.com/embed/video1ID',
    '#video2': '//youtube.com/embed/video2ID',
    '#video3': '//youtube.com/embed/video3ID'
}
if (window.location.hash && videos[window.location.hash]) {
     document.querySelector("#video iframe").src = videos[window.location.hash];
}
```

Also note that if you assign an `id` to the iframe itself then you can select it easier using

```
document.getElementById('videoIframe').src = videos[window.location.hash];
```

Comment: I don't quite have this worked out.  Can you show me what the HTML would look like?  I like the idea of not needing to mess with the span and just slap and id on the iFrame.

Comment: Don't know what I'm doing wrong, but here is the page I'm working with.  http://hannibalregional.com/test2#video2

Comment: https://gist.github.com/humbleRumble/b9d7b4ae6b70e9a9998a use that code and put it after the iframe. If the iframe doesn't exist when the script is executed then it won't run, and you need the correct embed urls for the videos. I've tested this on your page using the developer console and it works.

Comment: It makes sense that the iframe would have to be there before the script.  I've put the code in as you suggest, lines 823-825 in the source.  The Telerik editor changes the code slightly so I've done away with it as a variable.  I'm using the URL hannibalregional.com/test2#video2 to test.  I'm wondering if it's got something to do with the friendly URL rewriter that is built in the CMS?

Comment: I also noticed that the script is being changed where `&&` is encoded to `&amp;&amp;` which won't work. You'll have to find a way of inserting the script in such a way that the cms doesn't change it.

Comment: I noticed that and there is a setting in the editor for "Raw".  I used that and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: You didn't change the video url's from the placeholders, try the code in my gist above and copy it straight into the raw editor